flutter caused bottom overflowed
I am learning Flutter for the web and have encountered a problem with some widgets not fitting properly within the Chrome browser window. This results in a "bottom overflowed" error because no scrollbar appears to accommodate the extra content. Below is the layout structure of my application, where I primarily use Column and AspectRatio widgets. How can I modify my Flutter layout to ensure that all content fits within the viewable area and that scrollbars appear when necessary?

lib/basic_screen.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_layout/immutable_widget.dart'; //ALT+Enter on `Widget`
import 'package:flutter_layout/text_layout.dart';

class BasicScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BasicScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Scaffolds are also aware of your device’s specifics.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
        title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        actions: const [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.edit),
          ),
        ],
      ),
         body: Column(
        children: const [
          AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1.0,
            child: ImmutableWidget(),
          ),
          TextLayout(),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.lightBlue,
          child: const Center(
            child: Text("I'm a Drawer!"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

lib/immutable_widget.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as Math;

class ImmutableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImmutableWidget({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
      foregroundDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
        backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.colorBurn,
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: [
            Color(0xAA0d6123),
            Color(0x00000000),
            Color(0xAA0d6123),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
        child: Transform.rotate(
          angle: 180 / Math.pi, // Rotations are supplied in radians
          child: Container(
            width: 250,
            height: 250,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.purple,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple.withAlpha(120),
                    spreadRadius: 4,
                    blurRadius: 15,
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(1.0, 30)),
              ],
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
              child: _buildShinyCircle(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildShinyCircle() {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        gradient: RadialGradient(
          colors: [
            Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            Colors.blueAccent,
          ],
          center: Alignment(-0.3, -0.5),
        ),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(blurRadius: 20),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

lib/main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_layout/basic_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_layout/immutable_widget.dart';

void main() => runApp(const StaticApp());

class StaticApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const StaticApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      //home: const ImmutableWidget(), //Because or using Scaffolds.
      home: const BasicScreen(),
    );
  }
}

lib/text_layout.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextLayout({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Text(
          'Hello, World!',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        ),
        Text(
          'Text can wrap without issue',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
        ),
//make sure the Text below is all in one line:
        const Text(
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam at mauris massa. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquet eu nisl vitae tempus.'),
      ],
    );
  }
}


Wrap your column inside SingleChildScrollView
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: const [
        AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 1.0,
          child: ImmutableWidget(),
        ),
        TextLayout(),
      ],
    ),
  ),

Result: 
